# Как отловить переход по роуту и перейти на него в случае если пользователь нажмёт подтвердить в модалке (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет!
Появилась задача, есть форма заполнения заказа, нужно добавить функционал, а именно:

Перед выходом с роута создания заказа необходимо показывать модальное окно, с ответами типа да/нет, если пользователь нажимает да, переход осуществляется, если нет, то остаётся на том же роуте

Как можно правильно это реализовать?
Как отловить переход с нужного роута?

Пробовал использовать компонент  и window.onbeforeunload , но там нельзя использовать своё модальное окно
Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В React-router есть компонент [Prompt](https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt). Добавьте его в компонент, выход с которого вы хотите отлавливать, передав в него нужное сообщение.

Comment: Привет!
Попробовал компонент Prompt из react router, но мне бы хотелось бы видеть не браузерное окно, а своё кастомное, можно ли как-то переопределить всплывающее окно?

Comment: @forjke https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664622/how-to-display-component-using-react-router-prompt-to-prevent-or-allow-route-c Тут есть пример где реализовано это с кастомной модалкой.